# Short clip on Youtube of a couple aboard a spaceship that disintegrates

Tags: story-identification

Saw a trailer or short film on YouTube recently where two people are on-board a futuristic spaceship, they engage in conversation, perhaps some flirting and look through enormous window and then everything starts to fall apart and disintegrate. I am not sure but the clip might also feature a plethora of other people in the background. I am pretty sure it was not the “Passengers” movie, this one was more on a cheaper side.

I think they were some kind of space tourists, the destination was probably some other planet. They engage in a pleasant conversation and they might be even wearing space suits while inside. The disintegration of a ship was abrupt and violent.

What movie could this be?

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Right now this might not be enough to go on.

Comment: I think they were some kind of space tourists, the destination was probably some other planet. They engage in a pleasant conversation and they might be even wearing space suits while inside. The disintegration of a ship was abrupt and violent.

Comment: This is "Flatlander" by Larry Niven.

Comment: There are certainly strong elements in common with ["Flatlander"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatlander_(short_story)), but I don't recall hearing that it had been produced as video.

Comment: Blaaast... Now I think it might have been a sci-fi short I saw on Youtube. My bad guys, thanks for all the help. I will check out the Flatlander nevertheless.

Comment: Closest I can think of is from the trailer of _After Earth_, where you see the two main characters on the ship deep breathing with oxygen masks, and then one gets sucked out as the ship starts tearing apart. Doesn't match other aspects of what you're looking for though.